# MinGW-w64's gcc and Address Sanitizer

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, mingw-w64, address-sanitizer

Installing MinGW-w64 5.1 I find `-fsanitize=address` is available.  It compiles fine, and when it starts linking I get thousands of:

```
undefined reference to '__asan_report_load1'
undefined reference to '__asan_report_load4'
```

I googled and found libasan referenced various places, but also comments that when you include `-fsanitize=address` it automatically includes that library for linking. I searched the MinGW-w64 5.1 install dirctory for "asan" and it was not found anywhere.

What do I need to add on to use address sanitizing features in MinGW-w64?  Thank you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've looked quickly into release notes for 4.8, 4.9 and 5.1 - ASAN is not available for Windows

Comment: Unavailable uptil `g++ 12.2.0 (Rev3, Built by MSYS2 project)` so far.