# ffmpeg memory leak in the avcodec_open2 method

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, ffmpeg

I've developed an application which handles live video stream. The problem is that it should run as a service and over time I am noticing some memory increase. When I check the application with valgrind - it did not find any leak related issues.
So I've check it with google profile tools. This is a result(substracting the one of the first dumps from the latest) after approximately 6 hour run:

```
   30.0  35.7%  35.7%     30.0  35.7% av_malloc
    28.9  34.4%  70.2%     28.9  34.4% av_reallocp
    24.5  29.2%  99.4%     24.5  29.2% x264_malloc
```

When I check the memory on the graph I see, that these allocations are related to avcodec_open2. The client code is:

```
`           g_EncoderMutex.lock();
            ffmpeg_encoder_start(OutFileName.c_str(), AV_CODEC_ID_H264, m_FPS, width, height);
            for (pts = 0; pts < VideoImages.size(); pts++) {                
                m_frame->pts = pts;
                ffmpeg_encoder_encode_frame(VideoImages[pts].RGBimage[0]);
            }
            ffmpeg_encoder_finish();
            g_EncoderMutex.unlock()
```

The ffmpeg_encoder_start method is:

```
 void VideoEncoder::ffmpeg_encoder_start(const char *filename, int codec_id, int fps, int width, int height)
        {
            int ret;
            m_FPS=fps;
            AVOutputFormat * fmt = av_guess_format(filename, NULL, NULL);
            m_oc = NULL;
            avformat_alloc_output_context2(&m_oc, NULL, NULL, filename);

            m_stream = avformat_new_stream(m_oc, 0);
            AVCodec *codec=NULL;

            codec =  avcodec_find_encoder(codec_id);    
            if (!codec) 
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Codec not found\n");
                return; //-1
            }

            m_c=m_stream->codec;

            avcodec_get_context_defaults3(m_c, codec);

            m_c->bit_rate = 400000;
            m_c->width = width;
            m_c->height = height;
            m_c->time_base.num = 1;
            m_c->time_base.den = m_FPS;
            m_c->gop_size = 10;
            m_c->max_b_frames = 1;
            m_c->pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
            if (codec_id == AV_CODEC_ID_H264)
                av_opt_set(m_c->priv_data, "preset", "ultrafast", 0);

            if (m_oc->oformat->flags & AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER) 
                m_c->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;
            avcodec_open2( m_c, codec, NULL );

            m_stream->time_base=(AVRational){1, m_FPS};

            if (avio_open(&m_oc->pb, filename, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE) < 0)
            {
                printf( "Could not open '%s'\n", filename);
                exit(1);
            }            

            avformat_write_header(m_oc, NULL);
            m_frame = av_frame_alloc();
            if (!m_frame) {
                printf( "Could not allocate video frame\n");
                exit(1);
            }
            m_frame->format = m_c->pix_fmt;
            m_frame->width  = m_c->width;
            m_frame->height = m_c->height;
            ret = av_image_alloc(m_frame->data, m_frame->linesize, m_c->width, m_c->height, m_c->pix_fmt, 32);
            if (ret < 0) {
                printf("Could not allocate raw picture buffer\n");
                exit(1);
            }
        }
```

The ffmpeg_encoder_encode_frame is:

```
void VideoEncoder::ffmpeg_encoder_encode_frame(uint8_t *rgb) 
{
    int ret, got_output;
    ffmpeg_encoder_set_frame_yuv_from_rgb(rgb);
    av_init_packet(&m_pkt);
    m_pkt.data = NULL;
    m_pkt.size = 0;

    ret = avcodec_encode_video2(m_c, &m_pkt, m_frame, &got_output);
    if (ret < 0) {
        printf("Error encoding frame\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (got_output) 
    {

         av_packet_rescale_ts(&m_pkt,
                        (AVRational){1, m_FPS}, m_stream->time_base);
        m_pkt.stream_index = m_stream->index;
        int ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(m_oc, &m_pkt);

        av_packet_unref(&m_pkt);

    }

}
```

ffmpeg_encoder_finish code is:

```
void VideoEncoder::ffmpeg_encoder_finish(void) 
        {
            int got_output, ret;

            do {

                ret = avcodec_encode_video2(m_c, &m_pkt, NULL, &got_output);
                if (ret < 0) {
                    printf( "Error encoding frame\n");
                    exit(1);
                }
                if (got_output) {

                    av_packet_rescale_ts(&m_pkt,
                                (AVRational){1, m_FPS}, m_stream->time_base);
                    m_pkt.stream_index = m_stream->index;
                    int ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(m_oc, &m_pkt);

                    av_packet_unref(&m_pkt);
                }
            } while (got_output);

            av_write_trailer(m_oc);
            avio_closep(&m_oc->pb);

            avformat_free_context(m_oc);

            av_freep(&m_frame->data[0]);
            av_frame_free(&m_frame);

            av_packet_unref(&m_pkt);
            sws_freeContext(m_sws_context);
        }
```

This code runs multiple times in the loop.
So my question is - what am I doing wrong? maybe ffmpeg is using some kind of internal buffering? If so, how to disable it? Because such an increase in memory usage is unacceptable at all.

Comment: Which of those APIs return a pointer to memory that you are responsible for releasing?

Answer (score 3):

You didn't close encoder context. Add `avcodec_close(m_c)` to `ffmpeg_encoder_finish()`.

See [ffmpeg.org](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.5/group__lavf__core.html#gadcb0fd3e507d9b58fe78f61f8ad39827)

> User is required to call avcodec_close() and avformat_free_context() to clean up the allocation by avformat_new_stream().

Plus I don't see how `m_c` is allocated. Usually it is allocated with `avcodec_alloc_context` and must be deallocated with `av_free` (after closing of course).

Answer (score 2):

Don't use valgrind to check memory leaks for your own projects, use sanitizers, with these you can pin point the source of the leak. Check this out: [Multi-Threaded Video Decoder Leaks Memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48047739/multi-threaded-video-decoder-leaks-memory/48056848#48056848)

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I've already tried the sanitizer approach, but when I use that flags the application usually fails with bus error.

Comment: Ok, enable sanitizers run program within `gdb`, when it faults, use `backtrace` to see where it happens.

Comment: thing is I was able to turn off that part of my application - and without it memory does not increase. But still I cannot wrap my head around this ffmpeg issues. Seems like I am only one who has them.

Answer (score 1):

It's sufficient to call 'avcodec_free_context(m_c)', this procedure calls 'avcodec_close' and also de-allocates 'extradata'(if it's was allocated) and  'subtitle_header' (if it was allocated).