# Cannot find -lasan using address sanitizer in MinGW in Windows (MinGW)

Tags: qt, gcc, mingw, qt-creator, address-sanitizer

I'm trying to use the gcc address sanitizer in Qt by adding `CONFIG += sanitizer sanitize_address` to my `.pro` file but I'm getting an `error: cannot find -lasan`.

How should I install the library?

I'm using the MinGW provided by Qt but I could also try a standalone version.

---

Related question: [MinGW-w64's gcc and Address Sanitizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31144000/mingw-w64s-gcc-and-address-sanitizer/31151497)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately GCC does not support Asan on Windows: here's an excerpt from [libsanitizer/configure.tgt](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libsanitizer/configure.tgt):

```
case "${target}" in
  x86_64-*-linux* | i?86-*-linux*)
    ...
  powerpc*-*-linux*)
    ...
  sparc*-*-linux*)
    ...
  s390*-*-linux*)
    ...
  sparc*-*-solaris2.11*)
    ...
  arm*-*-linux*)
    ...
  mips*64*-*-linux*)
    ...
  mips*-*-linux*)
    ...
  aarch64*-*-linux*)
    ...
  x86_64-*-darwin[1]* | i?86-*-darwin[1]*)
    ...
  x86_64-*-solaris2.11* | i?86-*-solaris2.11*)
    ...
  *)
    UNSUPPORTED=1
    ;;
esac
```

Note that Clang supports it (with some effort - see [wiki](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizerWindowsPort) for details) and many people have successfully used it.

Comment: I can read this `ASAN, TSAN and USAN are great technologies which are available in GCC. Unfortunately they are not completely usable on Windows. A proper review and tests are needed before anything.` [here](http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php/contribute). Can you confirm it can't be used so I mark your answer as correct?

Comment: @JosuGoñi I've added some prooflinks. Note that adding support in GCC shouldn't be hard, just none of major contributors has been interested in it.

Comment: @JosuGoñi that excerpt now lives at https://www.mingw-w64.org/contribute/#thorough-status-report-for-sanitizers-asan-tsan-usan