# Cannot use fsanitize=address in minGW compiler

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, mingw-w64, address-sanitizer

**My C++ Setup INFO :**
OS - *Windows 10*,
IDE - *VS Code*,
compiler - *MinGw*

**ISSUE :**
I recently found sanitizers for C++ to catch some runtime errors like out of bound array access with `-fsanitize=address` and `-fsanitize=undefined` in my VS Code environment.

This is a simple program for out of bound array access :
[image]

in VS Code terminal being used is **CMD** when i tried to compile the program with this line `g++ -fsanitize=address check.cpp -o main.exe`
[image]

On hitting enter I got this error ( cannot find -lasan ) :
[image]

**here is the c++ code** ->

```
// Program to demonstrate 
// accessing array out of bounds
#include <iostream>
using namespace std ;
int main()
{
    int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    cout<<arr[0]<<endl;
      
    // arr[10] is out of bound
    cout<<arr[10]<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Cause(s)/Solution(s) for this issue**

1. How to fix cannot find -lasan ?
2. Does MinGW not support these sanitizers, if so, shall I use cygwin ?
3. Can I install clang on windows machine (if possible) to use this
   whole bunch of sanitizers ?
4. What are the other options to use besides using Visual Studio
   instead of VS Code ??
5. Any other suggestions

**NOTE : kindly suggest me suitable tags for this post (if I have used a wrong one or missed a crucial one)**

Comment: Apparently not supported by mingw but should be available in clang -   https://stackoverflow.com/a/55019187/4074081

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot find -lasan using address sanitizer in Qt Creator in Windows (MinGW)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55018627/cannot-find-lasan-using-address-sanitizer-in-qt-creator-in-windows-mingw)

Comment: @dewaffled Besides Clang any other options ?? Like Cygwin (if its an alternative to minGW) does it provide ASAN for windows ??